# How do I input whole array in 8 steps instead of 64 steps?

Tags: c++

In this example I have a problem with chessboard, I need to input a numbers assigning each to each one point whether queen resides on that point or not, but it's to much tedious to enter all 64 numbers instead of entering 8 numbers by 8 numbers to 8. So how do I go through this loop?
This is my code that asks for every of 64 points.
I just want the program to accept 64 numbers like this for example 11111111 then numbers again forming a new column and so forth to 8.

```
int board[8][8];
for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
{
  for(int j=0;j<8;j++)
  {
    cout<<"Enter the points";
    cin>>board[i][j];
  }
  cout<<endl;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You can type all the numbers on separate lines, or 8 numbers per line, and the code will work.

Comment: Load one string instead of 8 integers. Then convert that one string into 8 integers.

Comment: Could you please share an example of input/output that you expect for this program?

Comment: I just want the program to accept 64 numbers like this for example 11111111 then numbers again forming a new column and so forth to 8.

Comment: Please add this information to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
{
  std::string s;
  std::getline(cin, s);
  for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
    board[i][j] = s[j] - '0';
}
```

In this code snippet, each of the 8 lines is reading 8 different values as a single string, e.g. `"11001001"`. This string is then copied over to one row of the board. We have to subtract by `'0'` in this case, since we are reading in the numbers as `char`s, but are storing them as `int`s.

The copying can be done using an algorithm as well, like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
{
  std::string s;
  std::getline(cin, s);
  std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), board[i], 
                 [](auto c) { return c - '0'; });
}
```

Comment: You should explain how this works, why it's a/the solution, and what the upsides/downsides are.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this for auto generate:

```
int board[8][8];
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        board[i][j] = 8*i+j;
```